# "Floating point relative accuracy" problem in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have written this function in python:

```
def F(x):
    if e==0: 
        F = np.exp(-s*x)
    else:
        F = np.amax((1-(e*x))**(s/e))
    return F
```

X is a array, e and s are parameter values.

The function works fine when testing it with regular numbers, but when using it later on to make indices, I get this error.

```
/var/folders/ms/77r_86797xng4439fph6sg9h0000gn/T/ipykernel_19925/2944436554.py:6: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  F = np.amax((1-(e*x))**(s/e))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: What's the value range (min, max, min(abs())) of each variable?

Comment: What are `e` and `s`?  Global?  are you passing it in? etc.?  They are undefined in the example you provided.   So, give some examples of how this is actually used and what the values of the variables are

Comment: The problem in the title of the question seems unrelated to the warning message that you encountered. Please clarify the actual problem, and please include enough additional code so that the question is a [mcve].

Comment: You'll get the warning *RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power* if there are any negative values in `1 - (e*x)` and `s/e` is not an integer.